# Quota in Postfix, Dovecot with Maildir Not working

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, dovecot, maildir

I've some problem with quota with Maildir. If I install a plugin in Thunderbird that shows Quota's it's working and my quota is like 300%. But I can still send and recieve mails.

I'm not running any sql database, I'm only using the Maildir format to store the mails in the users home folder in Linux/Ubuntu.

```
quota = maildir:User quota
quota_rule = *:storage=5M
```

Please let me know if there's more from the configs you need to be able to help me with this.

Postfix Conf.

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 52428800
mydestination = mail.domain.com, domain.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mydomain = domain.com
myhostname = mail.domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8,,192.168.1.0/24 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = mail2.bahnhof.se
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_domains = example.com example2.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_transport = dovecot
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smptd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
```

Dovecot conf.

```
# 2.1.7: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.18.11-v7+ armv7l Debian 7.8 
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
listen = *
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_plugins = " quota"
namespace {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Drafts
    name = Drafts
  }
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Junk
    name = Junk
  }
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Sent
    name = Sent
  }
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Sent
    name = Sent Messages
  }
  mailbox {
    special_use = \Trash
    name = Trash
  }
  prefix = 
  name = inbox
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
plugin {
  autocreate = Trash
  autocreate2 = Sent
  autosubscribe = Trash
  autosubscribe2 = Sent
  quota = maildir
  quota_grace = 10%%
  quota_rule = *:storage=5M
  quota_status_nouser = DUNNO
  quota_status_overquota = 552 5.2.2 Mailbox is full
  quota_status_success = DUNNO
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
protocols = " imap"
service replication-notify-fifo {
  name = aggregator
}
service anvil-auth-penalty {
  name = anvil
}
service auth-worker {
  name = auth-worker
}
service {
  unix_listener {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
    path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
  }
  name = auth
}
service config {
  name = config
}
service dict {
  name = dict
}
service login/proxy-notify {
  name = director
}
service dns-client {
  name = dns_client
}
service doveadm-server {
  name = doveadm
}
service imap {
  name = imap-login
}
service login/imap {
  name = imap
}
service indexer-worker {
  name = indexer-worker
}
service indexer {
  name = indexer
}
service ipc {
  name = ipc
}
service lmtp {
  name = lmtp
}
service log-errors {
  name = log
}
service pop3 {
  name = pop3-login
}
service login/pop3 {
  name = pop3
}
service replicator {
  name = replicator
}
service login/ssl-params {
  name = ssl-params
}
service stats-mail {
  name = stats
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
protocol lmtp {
  service replication-notify-fifo {
    name = aggregator
  }
  service anvil-auth-penalty {
    name = anvil
  }
  service auth-worker {
    name = auth-worker
  }
  service auth-client {
    name = auth
  }
  service config {
    name = config
  }
  service dict {
    name = dict
  }
  service login/proxy-notify {
    name = director
  }
  service dns-client {
    name = dns_client
  }
  service doveadm-server {
    name = doveadm
  }
  service imap {
    name = imap-login
  }
  service login/imap {
    name = imap
  }
  service indexer-worker {
    name = indexer-worker
  }
  service indexer {
    name = indexer
  }
  service ipc {
    name = ipc
  }
  service lmtp {
    name = lmtp
  }
  service log-errors {
    name = log
  }
  service pop3 {
    name = pop3-login
  }
  service login/pop3 {
    name = pop3
  }
  service replicator {
    name = replicator
  }
  service login/ssl-params {
    name = ssl-params
  }
  service stats-mail {
    name = stats
  }
}
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = quota imap_quota
  service replication-notify-fifo {
    name = aggregator
  }
  service anvil-auth-penalty {
    name = anvil
  }
  service auth-worker {
    name = auth-worker
  }
  service auth-client {
    name = auth
  }
  service config {
    name = config
  }
  service dict {
    name = dict
  }
  service login/proxy-notify {
    name = director
  }
  service dns-client {
    name = dns_client
  }
  service doveadm-server {
    name = doveadm
  }
  service imap {
    name = imap-login
  }
  service login/imap {
    name = imap
  }
  service indexer-worker {
    name = indexer-worker
  }
  service indexer {
    name = indexer
  }
  service ipc {
    name = ipc
  }
  service lmtp {
    name = lmtp
  }
  service log-errors {
    name = log
  }
  service pop3 {
    name = pop3-login
  }
  service login/pop3 {
    name = pop3
  }
  service replicator {
    name = replicator
  }
  service login/ssl-params {
    name = ssl-params
  }
  service stats-mail {
    name = stats
  }
}
protocol lda {
  service replication-notify-fifo {
    name = aggregator
  }
  service anvil-auth-penalty {
    name = anvil
  }
  service auth-worker {
    name = auth-worker
  }
  service auth-client {
    name = auth
  }
  service config {
    name = config
  }
  service dict {
    name = dict
  }
  service login/proxy-notify {
    name = director
  }
  service dns-client {
    name = dns_client
  }
  service doveadm-server {
    name = doveadm
  }
  service imap {
    name = imap-login
  }
  service login/imap {
    name = imap
  }
  service indexer-worker {
    name = indexer-worker
  }
  service indexer {
    name = indexer
  }
  service ipc {
    name = ipc
  }
  service lmtp {
    name = lmtp
  }
  service log-errors {
    name = log
  }
  service pop3 {
    name = pop3-login
  }
  service login/pop3 {
    name = pop3
  }
  service replicator {
    name = replicator
  }
  service login/ssl-params {
    name = ssl-params
  }
  service stats-mail {
    name = stats
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and put the output of command `postconf -n` and `dovecot -n`

Comment: It is unclear from your question if you have actually configured postfix to check the quota before accepting delivery

Comment: Thanks for anwers, I've now edit the question and added the output of commands postconf -n and dovecot -n . Hope this can help!

Comment: It looks like my quota is filled up when I put mails in the trash, but when I have them in the INBOX they don't fill the quota.. That's strange??